# Trying to insert some values from csv file to cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

Trying to insert some values from reading the csv file to Cassandra table.
Tried with `mapper.save(object)` and `session.executeAsync(boundedstatement)`.
which will be better when I have to insert objects in a loop.

`mapper.save(object);// first approach`

`session.executeAsync(boundedStatement); // seconf approach`

Answer (score 1):

`mapper.save` is synchronous in nature where as `session.executeAsync(boundedStatement)` is async in nature. If there is no dependency between the objects in your loop you can make async calls for the inserts, so the insert can happen in parallel.

Also `Mapper` has a async variant, you can check it out 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/object_mapper/using/

Comment: thanks I tried with mapper.saveAsync also. which one would u recommend between mapper.saveAsync and session.executeAsync(boundedStatement).

Comment: As per my understanding  the simple object mapper, avoids most of the boilerplate when converting your domain classes to and from query results.

Comment: @TanviPagare : If you feel I have answered your question please can you accept my answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I believe its the same.